# MSVC Visual studio, error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'dx::RootBindings<1>'

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, directx-12

I am following a DirectX 12 tutorial series on YouTube. I tried to build the project using Visual Studio 2022 but I am getting the ***error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'dx::RootBindings<1>'***.

There are multiple instances where following kind of initialization is giving the same error.

```
static dx::RootBindings<1> rootBindings = {
    dx::ROOT_ELEMENT<DX_ROOT_TYPE_TABLE>(m_descHeapSrvCbv.get(0).gpuHandle),
};
```

I think GCC will be able to compile above code, but since I am building DirectX 12 project so I have to  use Microsoft MSVC compiler. Maybe some settings in the Visual Studio can resolve the error.

I am attaching the link to the GitHub repo and the code snippet for reference.

[GitHub Repo: Drawing a Triangle](https://github.com/Ohjurot/DX12-YT/releases/tag/VV.1).

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NxBh.png)

Comment: [cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'dx::RootBindings<1>](https://github.com/Ohjurot/DX12-YT/issues/1) - _"Please try out to clone and compile the code on any of the stable tags like https://github.com/Ohjurot/DX12-YT/tree/VV.3

The current main branch is not guaranteed to work since it is a bit ahead of the last video."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo tried this too, but the error still exists, maybe some visual studio configuration is causing the error.